# How do I ask an open question?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, specific-question

The question that I asked here:

[Open Problems Of Clay Mathematics Institute](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1125376/open-problems-of-clay-mathematics-institute)

has been put on hold since it is an opinion-based question.

So, how do I ask an open question NICELY, one whose answers are opinion-based? For one, I found this question:

[Open mathematical questions for which we really, really have no idea what the answer is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992965/open-mathematical-questions-for-which-we-really-really-have-no-idea-what-the-an?rq=1)

which was an open problem, and contained more or less the same content as to what I asked, but was well-responded to.

Please guide me as to what I should keep in mind while asking such question?

Comment: I believe the problem with your question is that it is unanswerable.  *If we knew* that the solutions to open problems were attainable from the current state of the art, we would most likely solve them.  But we don't, so we haven't.  (I might come back and write a fuller response later, but that's my first thought.)

Comment: Related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3860/unsolved-problem-asked-as-a-question-in-math-se http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9878/unsolvable-problems-asked-seriously-as-questions http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9974/can-we-only-ask-practical-questions-at-mse

Comment: Rule of thumb, any question which takes more than a few pages to answer is probably off-topic here. I think you can write a few books start from the two questions you used as example.

Answer (score 4):

". . .or all possible answers are too long for this format" Your question was way to long to be answered in a few paragraphs, also, opinion-based questions are *generally* off-topic on stack exchange.